# duckduckgo module not working in python 3.4.4

Tags: python, python-2to3, duckduckgo-api

Hi I got the following module from [here](https://github.com/crazedpsyc/python-duckduckgo)

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json as j
import sys

__version__ = 0.242


def query(query, useragent='python-duckduckgo '+str(__version__), safesearch=True, html=False, meanings=True, **kwargs):
    """
    Query DuckDuckGo, returning a Results object.
    Here's a query that's unlikely to change:
    >>> result = query('1 + 1')
    >>> result.type
    'nothing'
    >>> result.answer.text
    '1 + 1 = 2'
    >>> result.answer.type
    'calc'
    Keword arguments:
    useragent: UserAgent to use while querying. Default: "python-duckduckgo %d" (str)
    safesearch: True for on, False for off. Default: True (bool)
    html: True to allow HTML in output. Default: False (bool)
    meanings: True to include disambiguations in results (bool)
    Any other keyword arguments are passed directly to DuckDuckGo as URL params.
    """ % __version__

    safesearch = '1' if safesearch else '-1'
    html = '0' if html else '1'
    meanings = '0' if meanings else '1'
    params = {
        'q': query,
        'o': 'json',
        'kp': safesearch,
        'no_redirect': '1',
        'no_html': html,
        'd': meanings,
        }
    params.update(kwargs)
    encparams = urllib.urlencode(params)
    url = 'http://api.duckduckgo.com/?' + encparams

    request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': useragent})
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    json = j.loads(response.read())
    response.close()

    return Results(json)


class Results(object):

    def __init__(self, json):
        self.type = {'A': 'answer', 'D': 'disambiguation',
                     'C': 'category', 'N': 'name',
                     'E': 'exclusive', '': 'nothing'}.get(json.get('Type',''), '')

        self.json = json
        self.api_version = None # compat

        self.heading = json.get('Heading', '')

        self.results = [Result(elem) for elem in json.get('Results',[])]
        self.related = [Result(elem) for elem in
                        json.get('RelatedTopics',[])]

        self.abstract = Abstract(json)
        self.redirect = Redirect(json)
        self.definition = Definition(json)
        self.answer = Answer(json)

        self.image = Image({'Result':json.get('Image','')})


class Abstract(object):

    def __init__(self, json):
        self.html = json.get('Abstract', '')
        self.text = json.get('AbstractText', '')
        self.url = json.get('AbstractURL', '')
        self.source = json.get('AbstractSource')

class Redirect(object):

    def __init__(self, json):
        self.url = json.get('Redirect', '')

class Result(object):

    def __init__(self, json):
        self.topics = json.get('Topics', [])
        if self.topics:
            self.topics = [Result(t) for t in self.topics]
            return
        self.html = json.get('Result')
        self.text = json.get('Text')
        self.url = json.get('FirstURL')

        icon_json = json.get('Icon')
        if icon_json is not None:
            self.icon = Image(icon_json)
        else:
            self.icon = None


class Image(object):

    def __init__(self, json):
        self.url = json.get('Result')
        self.height = json.get('Height', None)
        self.width = json.get('Width', None)


class Answer(object):

    def __init__(self, json):
        self.text = json.get('Answer')
        self.type = json.get('AnswerType', '')

class Definition(object):
    def __init__(self, json):
        self.text = json.get('Definition','')
        self.url = json.get('DefinitionURL')
        self.source = json.get('DefinitionSource')


def get_zci(q, web_fallback=True, priority=['answer', 'abstract', 'related.0', 'definition'], urls=True, **kwargs):
    '''A helper method to get a single (and hopefully the best) ZCI result.
    priority=list can be used to set the order in which fields will be checked for answers.
    Use web_fallback=True to fall back to grabbing the first web result.
    passed to query. This method will fall back to 'Sorry, no results.' 
    if it cannot find anything.'''

    ddg = query('\\'+q, **kwargs)
    response = ''

    for p in priority:
        ps = p.split('.')
        type = ps[0]
        index = int(ps[1]) if len(ps) > 1 else None

        result = getattr(ddg, type)
        if index is not None: 
            if not hasattr(result, '__getitem__'): raise TypeError('%s field is not indexable' % type)
            result = result[index] if len(result) > index else None
        if not result: continue

        if result.text: response = result.text
        if result.text and hasattr(result,'url') and urls: 
            if result.url: response += ' (%s)' % result.url
        if response: break

    # if there still isn't anything, try to get the first web result
    if not response and web_fallback:
        if ddg.redirect.url:
            response = ddg.redirect.url

    # final fallback
    if not response: 
        response = 'Sorry, no results.'

    return response

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        q = query(' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
        keys = q.json.keys()
        keys.sort()
        for key in keys:
            sys.stdout.write(key)
            if type(q.json[key]) in [str,unicode,int]: print(':', q.json[key])
            else: 
                sys.stdout.write('\n')
                for i in q.json[key]: print('\t',i)
    else:
        print('Usage: %s [query]' % sys.argv[0])
```

This code seems to work properly in python 2.7 but in 3.4 I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python34\My programs\Novos\duckduckgo.py", line 2, in <module>
    import urllib2
ImportError: No module named 'urllib2'
```

I tried using 2to3 but it gave me the following code which didn't work either:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
import json as j
import sys

__version__ = 0.242


def query(query, useragent='python-duckduckgo '+str(__version__), safesearch=True, html=False, meanings=True, **kwargs):
    """
    Query DuckDuckGo, returning a Results object.
    Here's a query that's unlikely to change:
    >>> result = query('1 + 1')
    >>> result.type
    'nothing'
    >>> result.answer.text
    '1 + 1 = 2'
    >>> result.answer.type
    'calc'
    Keword arguments:
    useragent: UserAgent to use while querying. Default: "python-duckduckgo %d" (str)
    safesearch: True for on, False for off. Default: True (bool)
    html: True to allow HTML in output. Default: False (bool)
    meanings: True to include disambiguations in results (bool)
    Any other keyword arguments are passed directly to DuckDuckGo as URL params.
    """ % __version__

    safesearch = '1' if safesearch else '-1'
    html = '0' if html else '1'
    meanings = '0' if meanings else '1'
    params = {
        'q': query,
        'o': 'json',
        'kp': safesearch,
        'no_redirect': '1',
        'no_html': html,
        'd': meanings,
        }
    params.update(kwargs)
    encparams = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
    url = 'http://api.duckduckgo.com/?' + encparams

    request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': useragent})
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    json = j.loads(response.read())
    response.close()

    return Results(json)


class Results(object):

    def __init__(self, json):
        self.type = {'A': 'answer', 'D': 'disambiguation',
                     'C': 'category', 'N': 'name',
                     'E': 'exclusive', '': 'nothing'}.get(json.get('Type',''), '')

        self.json = json
        self.api_version = None # compat

        self.heading = json.get('Heading', '')

        self.results = [Result(elem) for elem in json.get('Results',[])]
        self.related = [Result(elem) for elem in
                        json.get('RelatedTopics',[])]

        self.abstract = Abstract(json)
        self.redirect = Redirect(json)
        self.definition = Definition(json)
        self.answer = Answer(json)

        self.image = Image({'Result':json.get('Image','')})


class Abstract(object):

    def __init__(self, json):
        self.html = json.get('Abstract', '')
        self.text = json.get('AbstractText', '')
        self.url = json.get('AbstractURL', '')
        self.source = json.get('AbstractSource')

class Redirect(object):

    def __init__(self, json):
        self.url = json.get('Redirect', '')

class Result(object):

    def __init__(self, json):
        self.topics = json.get('Topics', [])
        if self.topics:
            self.topics = [Result(t) for t in self.topics]
            return
        self.html = json.get('Result')
        self.text = json.get('Text')
        self.url = json.get('FirstURL')

        icon_json = json.get('Icon')
        if icon_json is not None:
            self.icon = Image(icon_json)
        else:
            self.icon = None


class Image(object):

    def __init__(self, json):
        self.url = json.get('Result')
        self.height = json.get('Height', None)
        self.width = json.get('Width', None)


class Answer(object):

    def __init__(self, json):
        self.text = json.get('Answer')
        self.type = json.get('AnswerType', '')

class Definition(object):
    def __init__(self, json):
        self.text = json.get('Definition','')
        self.url = json.get('DefinitionURL')
        self.source = json.get('DefinitionSource')


def get_zci(q, web_fallback=True, priority=['answer', 'abstract', 'related.0', 'definition'], urls=True, **kwargs):
    '''A helper method to get a single (and hopefully the best) ZCI result.
    priority=list can be used to set the order in which fields will be checked for answers.
    Use web_fallback=True to fall back to grabbing the first web result.
    passed to query. This method will fall back to 'Sorry, no results.' 
    if it cannot find anything.'''

    ddg = query('\\'+q, **kwargs)
    response = ''

    for p in priority:
        ps = p.split('.')
        type = ps[0]
        index = int(ps[1]) if len(ps) > 1 else None

        result = getattr(ddg, type)
        if index is not None: 
            if not hasattr(result, '__getitem__'): raise TypeError('%s field is not indexable' % type)
            result = result[index] if len(result) > index else None
        if not result: continue

        if result.text: response = result.text
        if result.text and hasattr(result,'url') and urls: 
            if result.url: response += ' (%s)' % result.url
        if response: break

    # if there still isn't anything, try to get the first web result
    if not response and web_fallback:
        if ddg.redirect.url:
            response = ddg.redirect.url

    # final fallback
    if not response: 
        response = 'Sorry, no results.'

    return response

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        q = query(' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
        keys = list(q.json.keys())
        keys.sort()
        for key in keys:
            sys.stdout.write(key)
            if type(q.json[key]) in [str,str,int]: print((':', q.json[key]))
            else: 
                sys.stdout.write('\n')
                for i in q.json[key]: print(('\t',i))
    else:
        print(('Usage: %s [query]' % sys.argv[0]))
```

Just so you know the second code snippet gave me the following error when i ran the query function:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    query("foobar")
  File "E:\Python34\duckduckgo.py", line 45, in query
    json = j.loads(response.read())
  File "E:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

So could anyone tell me what I did wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found out the soultion for it myself.
After converting the code to python 3, to solve the `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'` error, replace

```
json = j.loads(response.read())`
```

with `

```
reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")   
json = j.loads(reader(response).read())`
```

and add `import codecs` at the top of the code.

This fix works like a charm!

Comment: Or without needing to import a module: `.read().decode('UTF-8')`

Comment: Yeah, you could do that too